# SQL script to change the structure of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on a SQL database (Microsoft SQL Server 2008)

I have a table like this

```
Country     Gender           Number         
---------+---------------+-----------+
Russia       Male              50000                
Russia       Female            40000 
Russia       Unknown           30000
India        Male              45678                
India        Female            21354  
China        Male              37878                
China        Female            45686
China        Unknown           24534
France       Male              45378                
France       Female            49783
```

Is there an sql select script that can return a table like this:

```
    Country      Male             Female      Unknown   
---------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+
Russia       50000            40000        30000             
India        45678            21354        0
China        37878            45686        24534
France       45378            49783        0
```

Please note that some countries do not have "Unkown" data so in this case it should be 0.

I tried a couple of things but I did not get any close results. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pivot` operator for such kind of queries:

```
select Country,
    IsNull([Male], 0) Male,
    IsNull([Female], 0) Female,
    IsNull([Unknown], 0) Unknown
from TableName t
   pivot (sum(Number) for Gender in ([Male], [Female], [Unknown])) p
```

or `... pivot max(Number) for ...` if you know that `(Country, Gender)` combination is unique in original data.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this query

```
select
    T.Country,
    max(case when T.Gender = 'Male' then T.Number else 0 end) as Male,
    max(case when T.Gender = 'Female' then T.Number else 0 end) as Female,
    max(case when T.Gender = 'Unknown' then T.Number else 0 end) as Unknown
from Table1 as T
group by T.Country
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9ea2/1)